# I need to find the point on line A that is perpendicular to line B at a specific point (ptb) in 3d

Tags: 3d, line, point

I have line A, I have three points along this line and the direction.
I have line B, I have three points along this line and the direction. 
Given one of the points on B (called ptb), I want to find point pta on line A such that the line ptb-pta is perpendicular to line B. 
This is in 3D.

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? Or are you using any library/platform such as octave/matlab that can calculate this for you?

Comment: I am using Fortran77 so I am not using libraries, I'm coding the equations myself